# What is the meaning of 磨了边?

Tags: meaning-in-context, mandarin

While I was trying to read a Chinese novelette, I came across this sentence:

白色衬衫和褐色裤子，这是他唯一一套体面衣服，衬衫袖口磨了边，他把袖子卷到胳膊肘。

My initial guess was that 磨边 would mean something such as the edge of something, but it doesn't make sense in this sentence.

Can someone help me? I also don't understand why there is a 了 between 磨 and 边. Is 磨边 a separable word?

Answer (score 1):

磨 means worn, or damaged, which is used as a verb in this sentence, and 边 means the edges.
When you put a "了" in the middle, The meaning of “磨了边” is
'The “边” has been “磨”', to describe that the shirt has been worn for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

磨了边: worn at the edges

白色衬衫和褐色裤子，
A white shirt and brown trousers,
这是他唯一一套体面衣服，
are his only presentable clothes,
衬衫袖口磨了边，
the cuffs worn at the edges,
他把袖子卷到胳膊肘。
he rolls the sleeves up to his elbows.

Comment: What gives the meaning of wearing in the sentence? What is the function of 边 there? I don't quite understand this structure

Comment: 边 = the edge (of the cuffs) https://propercloth.com/reference/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/SleeveLength-Diptic.jpg

Comment: @Vinícius do Carmo Melício I could have written "frayed" instead of "worn". Look it up!

Comment: @ViníciusdoCarmoMelício please see Jack Chen's answer about where is the meaning of wearing from.

Answer (score 0):

衬衫袖口磨了边 - The end of the cuff of his shirt is worn due to years of rubbing with the wrist and hard objects. This is a descriptive phrase that echos 他唯一一套体面衣服 (his only presentable shirt) to make the point - he is either quite poor or a money savor (節省/簡的人).

"了" indicates the action (磨) on the object (袖口) is completed in the time past.